# How do I give my websites an icon for iPhone?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, favicon, apple-touch-icon

How do I set the icon that appears proper on the `iPhone` for the websites I have created?

Comment: I also found the `apple-touch-icon` information on the [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) as well as `apple-mobile-web-app-capable` meta tag for full screen mode.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your head section:`<link rel="icon" href="/your-icon-url"/>`