# What are the correct pixel dimensions for an apple-touch-icon?

Tags: iphone, favicon, apple-touch-icon

I'm not sure what the correct size should be.

Many sites seem to repeat that the apple-touch-icon should be 57x57 pixels but cite a broken link as their source.

[Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakeYourWebsiteMobileAndIPhoneFriendlyAddHomeScreenIPhoneIconsAndAdjustTheViewPort.aspx)'s and [playgroundblues](http://playgroundblues.com/posts/2008/jan/15/iphone-bookmark-iconage/)'s comments suggest different sizes including 163x163 and 60x60.

Apple's own [apple.com icon](http://www.apple.com/apple-touch-icon.png) is 129x129!

See my related question:
[How do I give my web sites an icon for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505/how-do-i-give-my-web-sites-an-icon-for-iphone)

Comment: Related: [Why am I getting error for apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12480497/367456) and an additional good online resource seems to be:  [*Everything you always wanted to know about touch icons* (Mar 2011; by Mathias Bynens)](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons)

Comment: Now Apple.com's icon is 152x152 ...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It seems that Apple guidelines as of August 3, 2010 now include the "High resolution" images (for iPhone 4) in their "required" icon sizes.

Looks like we need to provide both a 57x57 and a 114x114 image now, as well as a 640x960 title image.

See [Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2) (Javascript required) which is part of a whole document:

- [iOS Human Interface Guidelines (2013; by Apple Inc; PDF; 26,3 MB)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/MobileHIG.pdf)

Comment: I had some trouble getting the title images to work. Found a working example here: https://gist.github.com/472519 (`<!-- STARTUP IMAGES -->` section)

Comment: Note that iPads use the following sizes for icons: 72x72 1st and 2nd gen; 144x144 for 3rd gen "Retina".

Comment: Since the OP is talking about the apple-touch-icon (i.e. the image iOS plucks from a website to display as an icon on the Home screen), and not a native app's own icons, the 640 x 940 title image is not relevant here. (That said there is a 'Start Up' image of 320 x 480, as described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW4)

Comment: This link no longer works, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW4 instead

Answer (score 3):

Depends on how much detail you want it to have, it needs to have the aspect ratio of 1:1 (basically - it needs to be square)

I would go with the Apple's own 129*129

Answer (score 3):

[Apple specs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) specify new sizes for iOS7:

- 60x60
- 76x76
- 120x120
- 152x152

Whereas old sizes for iOS6 and prior are:

- 57x57
- 72x72
- 114x114
- 144x144

By the way, precomposed icons are deprecated.

As a consequence, to support but new devices (running iOS7) and older (iOS6 and prior), these 8 pictures must be present and the generic code is:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">    
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
```

In addition, [you should create a 152x152 picture named `apple-touch-icon.png`](http://realfavicongenerator.net/faq#why_high_res_touch_icon).

You might want to know that this [favicon generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) can generate all these pictures at once. Full disclosure: I'm the author of this site.

Answer (score 1):

The official size is 57x57. I would recommend using the exact size simply due to the fact that it takes less memory when loaded (unless Apple caches the scaled representation). With that said, [Rex is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598/what-are-the-correct-pixel-dimensions-for-an-apple-touch-icon#1599) that any square size will work

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a "correct size". Since the iPhone really is running OSX, the icon rendering system is pretty robust. As long as you give it a high-quality image with the right aspect ratio and a resolution at least as high as the actual output will be, the OS will downscale very cleanly. My site uses a 158x158 and the icon looks pixel-perfect on the iPhone screen.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated list October 2014, iOS8**

List for iPhone and iPad with and without retina

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="touch-icon-ipad.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="touch-icon-iphone-6-plus.png">
```

**Update 2014 iOS 8:**

For iOS 8 and iPhone 6 plus

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="touch-icon-iphone-6-plus.png">
```

iPhone 6 uses the same 120 x 120 px image as iPhone 4 and 5 the rest is the same as for iOS 7

**Update 2013 iOS7:**

For iOS 7 the recommended resolutions changed:

- for iPhone Retina from 114 x 114 px to 120 x 120 px
- for iPad Retina from 144 x 144 px to 152 x 152 px

The other resolution are still the same

- 57 x 57 px default
- 76 x 76 px for iPads without retina

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to bother for correct size any more. If you have iTunes artwork file (i.e. file of 1024*1024 size) of your icon, then I have created this application which will provide you all the icons based on information provided [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html). Get the [application from here](https://github.com/rptwsthi/AlliOSIconsWithProperName), and follow the instructions in readme file to create all the required icons for iOS application.