# How to save web page as desktop icon (bookmark?) on iphone/android?

Tags: iphone, icons, desktop, shortcut, bookmarks

Is it possible to prompt the user if they want to save a URL to their desktop (as a desktop shortcut icon) on the iphone or android? I've seen this in the google calendar on the iphone... a little prompt slides up from the bottom of the screen asking if you want to install the google calendar app, but I'm pretty sure it's just a google calendar desktop shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="...">
```

to the HEAD element of your document.

For more info, check out this thread:

[What size should apple-touch-icon.png be for iPad and iPhone 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997437/what-size-should-apple-touch-icon-png-be-for-ipad-and-iphone-4)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found for iDevices is the Mobile Bookmark Bubble found here: http://code.google.com/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/

This is a small javascript library that adds a pop up bubble at the bottom of your iDevice screen and points to the '+' button.

I haven't found a good solution for Android since there are so many steps. If anybody finds one, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks! I checked it out and I'm not sure that's a good solution anymore. The code shows a little "bubble" that points to the "+" (plus) icon at the bottom of the safari window, which no longer exists on IOS 4. The plus icon has been replaced with a different icon that opens a menu of options, one of which is "Add To Home Screen". However, your link was helpful since I got to review some code, and found that "<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="...">" in the head of your document specifies the icon to use.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin might be a good solution:

http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen