# iOS icon for Add to Home Screen turns black

Tags: ios, wordpress, apple-touch-icon

I'm not terribly familiar with the code to add icons for iOS (and Android) when you select "Add to Home Screen", but I used the following, based on what I read:

```
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="http://www.redtypewriter.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/57.jpg"/>  
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="http://www.redtypewriter.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/72.jpg"/>  
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="http://www.redtypewriter.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/114.jpg"/>
```

The code seems to work, but after I add it to my home screen, after some time, the icon disappears and I'm left with a black square in place of the icon? What's happening? The site is: http://www.redtypewriter.com/ if you want to take a look, and I am using a custom WordPress theme.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

There are two mains reasons to get black icons:

- Using JPG pictures (iOS prefers PNG)
- Using PNG with transparent regions. iOS fills transparent regions with black.

In your case, this is because your pictures are in JPG format instead of PNG.

With you original pictures, I observed three issues:

- The black icon, as you described it.
- It took some time for my device to show the icon (eg. when adding to the home screen). During the first few seconds, I only saw default icons. This is not that unusual, but I was a bit surprised.
- When bookmarking, my device didn't use your icons but another one:
  [image: "RT" icon in bookmarks]

As soon as I converted them to PNG and change the HTML code accordingly, all issues were fixed at once.

In addition, [you don't define enough pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110776/apple-touch-icon-for-websites/21144916#21144916). For example, your icon won't look great on a Retina iPad.

Comment: I have png files for my site, but it still shows up as black on the iPhone and iPad even though it's white. Any other ideas?

Comment: Transparency produces such result: transparent areas are filled with black. http://realfavicongenerator.net/blog/apple-touch-icon-turns-black/ . Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: By using the `apple-touch-icon-precomposed` keys (as opposed to `apple-touch-icon`) plus removing the alpha channel from our PNGs, we managed to solve the problem. Thanks a lot!

One way of removing the alpha channel is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322750/replace-transparency-in-png-images-with-white-background