# Different favicon for different routes

Tags: html, favicon

I supply my client with their own website with a different route, for example they have

```
https://example.com/client1
https://example.com/client2
https://example.com/client3
```

Now is it possible to have a different favicon for each site so if their users add the shortcut to their phone is has their own logo?

Comment: Of course. Really, all you need to do is modify the existing tag in the <head>

Answer (score 0):

Favicon is declared on each page - classic:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
...
```

where `favicon.ico` is a name of the icon file. The default is `favicon` but you can use any file names. Problems arise when you want to do it perfectly, or pamper your client...
Take a look at this [...favicons...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956465/favicon-standard-2020-svg-ico-png-and-dimensions)
To be sure you understand - each file must be a correctly made square of the appropriate  type and size - a lot of squares with the same logo in separate files...
Good practice - all favicons in the root directory - browsers look for it there, not elsewhere.
Another good practice - multiple favicons should look like siblings, a different colour or a small detail but generally have to be similar, the same style.