# How could I give my web application both a normal iPhone homescreen icon and a retina display icon?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app

Some web apps still have the old icon resolutions for iPhone 3GS and before. They look like crap on iPhone 4 screens though. I want to provide two icons, one at each resolution. But how do I code it to know which icon to serve up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find your answer in the [Safari Developer Library: Configuring Web Applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html).
See also [Stackoverflow Question: "What are the correct pixel dimensions for an apple-touch-icon?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598/what-are-the-correct-pixel-dimensions-for-an-apple-touch-icon)