# Keep getting 404's for apple-touch-icon.png

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, safari, apple-touch-icon

We keep getting 404's for the following two files:

```
/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png: 685 Time(s)
/apple-touch-icon.png: 523 Time(s)
```

I have been scouring my mobile website archive for the culprit to this 404, and there is no place in my code that is directing to `apple-touch-icon.png`.

Performing a `Find in folder...` in Sublime Text 2 provides zero results for `apple-touch-icon`:

```
Searching 100 files for "apple-touch-icon"

0 matches across 0 files
```

We are using the Apple meta tags for webapps:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

Will usage of these meta tags cause an iPhone to search for an `apple-touch-icon` by default?  We are not providing an icon, but should we be?  We would really just like to remove this 404.

Browsing Apple's [Developer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html) provided no hints that reinforce my theory.

The plot thickens even further when we discovered this is happening on iOS and Android,  regardless of browser.  Firefox, Safari, & Chrome are all trying to find this `apple-touch-icon`.

I used HTML5 Mobile Boilerplate as a starter for my WebApp, which has a file called `helper.js`.  `helper.js` has this function inside of it which I removed from our code:

```
/**
     * iOS Startup Image helper
     */

    MBP.startupImage = function() {
        var portrait;
        var landscape;
        var pixelRatio;
        var head;
        var link1;
        var link2;

        pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
        head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

        if (navigator.platform === 'iPad') {
            portrait = pixelRatio === 2 ? 'img/startup/startup-tablet-portrait-retina.png' : 'img/startup/startup-tablet-portrait.png';
            landscape = pixelRatio === 2 ? 'img/startup/startup-tablet-landscape-retina.png' : 'img/startup/startup-tablet-landscape.png';

            link1 = document.createElement('link');
            link1.setAttribute('rel', 'apple-touch-startup-image');
            link1.setAttribute('media', 'screen and (orientation: portrait)');
            link1.setAttribute('href', portrait);
            head.appendChild(link1);

            link2 = document.createElement('link');
            link2.setAttribute('rel', 'apple-touch-startup-image');
            link2.setAttribute('media', 'screen and (orientation: landscape)');
            link2.setAttribute('href', landscape);
            head.appendChild(link2);
        } else {
            portrait = pixelRatio === 2 ? "img/startup/startup-retina.png" : "img/startup/startup.png";
            portrait = screen.height === 568 ? "img/startup/startup-retina-4in.png" : portrait;
            link1 = document.createElement('link');
            link1.setAttribute('rel', 'apple-touch-startup-image');
            link1.setAttribute('href', portrait);
            head.appendChild(link1);
        }

        //hack to fix letterboxed full screen web apps on 4" iPhone / iPod
        if ((navigator.platform === 'iPhone' || 'iPod') && (screen.height === 568)) {
            if (MBP.viewportmeta) {
                MBP.viewportmeta.content = MBP.viewportmeta.content
                    .replace(/\bwidth\s*=\s*320\b/, 'width=320.1')
                    .replace(/\bwidth\s*=\s*device-width\b/, '');
            }
        }
    };
```

After removing this, we still get 404's. I am stumped.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Chrome on iOS will also fetch it because we use the iOS webview which Safari uses to make the browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting error for apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12480497/why-am-i-getting-error-for-apple-touch-icon-precomposed-png)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Will usage of these meta tags cause an iPhone to search for an
>   apple-touch-icon by default? We are not providing an icon, but should
>   we be? We would really just like to remove this 404.

Yes. Wenn you add

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

to your site it means that the user can create a bookmark on his home screen which is not opened in Safari but in a webview which looks like a "native" app. You should provide these images as kind of app icon for the home screen.

This might be the hint you were looking for: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

Comment: Great, thanks for the response and the link.  That definitely makes sense to me.  I'm still a bit confused as to why these tags also cause 404's for Firefox and Chrome mobile browsers on Android too, though.  I will remove the meta tags and keep an eye on the error logs for now. Thanks!

Comment: This feature is called web clips and might also be supported by other browsers. Chrome for instance allows you to place some bookmarks in your "new tab" screen. These bookmarks have also large icons but of course you're right it's kind of confusing.

Comment: I guess they assume yes. Try adding the first meta tag with `content="no"`. If it still occurs you should ask a new question.