# Missing files listed in error.log

Tags: apache, http, web, server-side, dreamhost

Today I stumbled upon a folder on my web host called 'error.log'. I thought I'd take a look.

I see multiple 'file does not exist' errors - there are three types of entries:

- robots.txt
- missing.html
- apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png

I have some guesses about what these files are used for, but would like to know definitively:

- What are the files in question?
- Should I add them to my server?
- What prompts an error log to be written for these? Is it someone explicitly requesting them? If so, who and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `robots.txt` file is read by web crawlers/robots to allow/disallow it from scraping resources on your server. However, it's not mandatory for a robot to read this file, but the nice ones do. There are some further examples at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt An example file may look like and would reside in the web root directory:

```
User-agent: *   # All robots
Disallow: /     # Do not enter website
```

or

```
User-Agent: googlebot   # For this robot
Disallow: /something    # do not enter
```

The `apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png` is explained https://stackoverflow.com/a/12683605/722238

I believe the usage of `missing.html` is used by some as a customized 404 page. It's possible that a robot may be configured to scrape this file, hence the requests for it.

You should add a robots.txt file if you want to control the resources a robot will scrape off your server. As said before, it's not mandatory for a robot to read this file.

If you wanted to add the other two files to remove the error messages you could, however, I don't believe it is necessary. There is nothing to say that joe_random won't make a request on your server for `/somerandomfile.txt` in which case you will get another error message for another file that doesn't exist. You could then just redirect them to a customized 404 page.