# Rails(5.1.1) asset pipeline ,sprockets error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

In my rails app I used three gems for authentication and styling, they are `devise`, `twitter-bootstrap-rails` and `devise-bootstrap-views`.

After following all the steps in the guides, I started my rails server an error showed up saying

> The asset "apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png" is not present in the asset pipeline.

[image]

What does it mean and how can I sort it out?

Comment: Well, is it present in the correct folder `app/assets/images`?

Comment: were you able to fix this?

Comment: @vikram i just changed my rails version from 5 to 4. after that every thing is working good.

Answer (score 0):

Revert to the original behaviour by adding

```
Rails.application.config.assets.unknown_asset_fallback = true
```

to the file `assets.rb` in `config/initializers`